# Serialization in Android

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am trying to Serialize paint and path in android. When I am write a object to Objectoutputstream the Notserializabale exception is fired. I am also overwite a writeObject() methods in serializabale class .

Here is the code.

```
public class msgContainar implements Serializable 
{
/**
 * 
 */
public msgContainar()
{

}
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Path pathStack;
private Paint paintStack;

public Path getPathStack() 
{
    return pathStack;
}

public void setPathStack(Path pathStack) 
{
    this.pathStack = pathStack;
}

public Paint getPaintStack() 
{
    return paintStack;
}
public void setPaintStack(Paint paintStack) 
{
    this.paintStack = paintStack;
}

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
{

    try
    {
    Paint p=new Paint();
    p.set(paintStack);

    Path path=new Path();

    path.addPath(pathStack);

    out.writeObject(path);
    out.writeObject(p);

    }catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("err",""+e);
    }

}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException{

    try{
    Paint p=new Paint();
    p=paintStack;

    Path path=new Path();

    path=pathStack;

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("err",""+e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) nor [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) implements the [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.  To work around this, you can create your own custom subclasses that extend `Path` and `Paint` and implement `Serializable`.