# Convert Myobject to byte

Tags: java, android

I want to object AuditContainer convert to byte and then save in file:

```
public class AuditContainer implements Serializable {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path mPath;
    private int x,y;
    private String text;
    boolean is_text;
```

Problem is because Paint and Path must be serialized, but it cant..
Firstly i want make serialization for this class, but i have got one truble, i cant save all things which i need. 
My question is how i can convert AuditoContainer to byte? Is it Posible? and which is princips/options for save my class in file/database?

I need help, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641434/serialization-in-android

Comment: Why do you need to serialize them? Perhaps it is possible to create another class that stores the values? Separation of concern.

Comment: is any anathor option to save arraylist<AuditContainer> in file, if serialization is silly pleas help me :)

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to write the status of the object to a file, is better if you don't use serialization. Serialization has lots of flaws and is hard to get it done correctly, while you can save the properties of your object easily as strings in the file.

Comment: nice idea, you mean to try to do a saving and loading throw String values, and use a parsing style while loading the data once again ... nice one really

Comment: Yes, I would choose that option. Serialization makes sense only if the object needs change it's JVM at runtime, but most applications won't never do that.

Comment: There are a multitude of libraries that can be used to assist in the saving/loading. One of my favorites is `Jackson`. http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 1):

want serialization example ?

ok here is one (make sure that all your Objects mentioned in your variables are serializable as well)

```
    public void save(AuditContainer auditContainer, File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);    
            oos.writeObject(auditContainer);
    }finally{
        if(oos != null){
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
    }
    }
}


public AuditContainer load(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    AuditContainer auditContainer = null;

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(ois);
        auditContainer = (AuditContainer)ois.readObject();
    }finally{
        if(ois != null){
            ois.close();
        }
    }
    return auditContainer;
}
```