# android.graphics.Paint is not Serializable Exception while Serializing

Tags: java, android, json, xml, serialization

I have used android.graphics.paint in Myclass and now i want to serialize Myclass to file, 
but I'm `getting android.graphics.Paint is not Serializable Exception`

this is because `android.graphics.paint` does not implements serializable interface

is there any way that i can serialize Myclass to file?

Comment: mark the painter object as transient. It will be excluded from the serialization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Serialization with non serializable parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95181/java-serialization-with-non-serializable-parts)

Comment: Here that has helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641434/serialization-in-android